# Authorization strategy on a per-client basis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, authorization, pundit

I have a Rails 4 application. I use *devise* for authentication and *opro* for providing oauth2 with my API. All requests are authorized with *pundit* policies and until now, this setup was totally fine.

Currently, my **authorization** is always done on a **per-user** basis. This makes sense, as usually every request is done on behalf of a particular user who is either authenticated in a session or by providing the oauth-token.

The new challenge is: I have certain API-consumers (let me call them *devices* from now on), whose requests cannot be seen as requests from a particular user. One is an *Asterisk Server* that can exchange information with the API, another is a *GPS Tracking Box* that continuously pushes trackpoints to the API.

Thus, I need to authorize certain API-operations on a **per-device** basis, meaning there is not necessarily a `current_user` available. Having no `current_user` however screws up my authorization concept.

I have already considered several approaches to the problem:

- creating dedicated users for each device and authorizing them to do the specific action

  - pro: does not screw up my authorization scheme
  - contra: would mean to rethink the `User`-Model, as currently I only have "natural users" that require name, birthday, email, etc
- creating dedicated controllers with adapted authorization scheme

  - pro: high flexibility
  - contra:

    - authentication for devices required
    - extra API endpoints required, does not feel very DRY

I am searching for a best-practice approach for such a situation. I believe this is not an extra-ordinary problem and there must be good solutions for this out there.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate layer that does the authorization check as well as global attributes called `caller_id` and `caller_type` (these are just examples).

You then want to implement a logic e.g.:

- `if caller_type == device and caller_id == ... then`
- `if caller_type == user and caller_id == ... then`

To do that you can just custom-code your own little class. Alternatively you could use [XACML](http://oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=xacml) to define your authorization logic. See this [blog post](http://developers.axiomatics.com/blog/index/entry/using-xacml-to-apply-fine-grained-access-control-on-java-servlets-with-filters.html) which applies XACML to servlets. The same principle could be done for your Rails application.

HTH,
David.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, but let me ask a few details. I considered XACML a while ago, but I felt there was no good rails implementation yet. I therefore implemented authorization with the Pundit gem and this works fine. Concerning the 'separate layer' you mention, do you mean something like a polymorphic user model, e.g. having a generic `User` model and more specific `NaturalUser` and `DeviceUser` and then make my authorization on the generic base class? Or do you suggest adding middleware?

Comment: Regarding the separate layer, I meant separating authZ code from business logic. IF you use the pundit gem, then you are already doing that. Using a generic User class that is then extended makes a lot of sense IMHO. I'm not aware of any RoR XACML implementation but that doesn't matter if you have the means to invoke the XACML engine from Ruby, right? Axiomatics - the vendor I work for - provides an API so that you can call the XACML engine from multiple languages including Ruby.